# python apt-get list upgrades

Tags: python, apt-get

How can I get a list of upgrade packages available and write it to file using python?

When I run `apt-get upgrade > output`
it works in bash. I think I have to send the trap signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) in the python program.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

---

I tried this on the code now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

apt = subprocess.Popen([r"apt-get", "-V", "upgrade", ">", "/usr/src/python/upgrade.log"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
apt_stdin = apt.communicate()[0]
```

but it exits and does not write to the file.

---

This works but I am getting error when I port this to other Debian systems:

```
import apt

cache=apt.Cache()
cache.update()
cache.open(None)
cache.upgrade()
for pkg in cache.get_changes():
#       print pkg.name,  pkg.summary
        fileHandle = open('/tmp/upgrade.log', 'a')
        fileHandle.write(pkg.name + " - " + pkg.summary + "\n")
```

and the error....

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/apt/__init__.py:18: FutureWarning: apt API not stable yet
  warnings.warn("apt API not stable yet", FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apt-notify.py", line 13, in <module>
    for pkg in cache.get_changes():
AttributeError: 'Cache' object has no attribute 'get_changes'
```

Comment: maybe your other debian systems are using an older version of python-apt

Comment: yes correct, where the code runs uses python-apt 0.7.94.2 and the systems which give error uses python-apt 0.7.7.1+nmu1, i cant just update them without a OS version change....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the python-apt module eg.

```
import apt
cache=apt.Cache()
cache.update()
cache.open(None)
cache.upgrade()
for pkg in cache.getChanges():
    print pkg.sourcePackageName, pkg.isUpgradeable
```

also read the link in badp's comment

Comment: According to the [example](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html#example), you're missing the step of re- [`open()`](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html#apt.cache.Cache.open) -ing the cache after doing the update.

Comment: cool that worked, thanks for that, now that i have made the script, its spewing out error on other systems..

Comment: @krisdigitx, you'll have to make sure python-apt is installed on all those systems

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python module `subprocess` and close `stdin` to tell the child process that it should exit.

Comment: Instead of "> outputfile", you can use stdout=PIPE and get the output via `communicate`

Answer (score 0):

Using > to redirect output to a file is something the shell does.  Your (updated) code is passing the > to apt-get instead, which has no idea what to do with it.  Adding `shell=True` to your invocation of `subprocess.Popen` will run the argument list through the shell first, which will make the redirect work.

Comment: Adding shell=True is an inefficient and messy way to do redirection. Much better to use the subprocess module's own redirection - although in this specific case, the python-apt module is better still.