# python apt_pkg to obtain individual pkg details?

Tags: python, debian, apt

I've been using a combination of apt_pkg and apt libraries to obtain the following details from each package:

```
package.name
package.installedVersion
package.description
package.homepage
package.priority
```

I was able to obtain what I needed in the following manner, which I'm not entirely sure it's the best method of obtaining the results:

```
import apt_pkg, apt

apt_pkg.InitConfig()
apt_pkg.InitSystem()

aptpkg_cache = apt_pkg.GetCache() #Low level 
apt_cache = apt.Cache() #High level

apt_cache.update()
apt_cache.open()

pkgs = {}
list_pkgs = []

for package in aptpkg_cache.Packages:
       try:
          #I use this to pass in the pkg name from the apt_pkg.packages
          #to the high level apt_cache which allows me to obtain the
          #details I need. Is it better to just stick to one library here?
          #In other words, can I obtain this with just apt_pkg instead of using apt?

          selected_package = apt_cache[package.name]

          #Verify that the package can be upgraded
          if check_pkg_status(package) == "upgradable":
           pkgs["name"] = selected_package.name
               pkgs["version"] = selected_package.installedVersion
               pkgs["desc"] = selected_package.description
               pkgs["homepage"] = selected_package.homepage
               pkgs["severity"] = selected_package.prority

               list_pkgs.append(pkgs)
          else:
               print "Package: " + package.name + " does not exist"
               pass #Not upgradable?

        except:
          pass #This is one of the main reasons why I want to try a different method.
              #I'm using this Try/Catch because there are a lot of times that when
              #I pass in package.name to apt_cache[], I get error that package does not
              #exists... 


def check_pkg_status(package):
        versions = package.VersionList
        version = versions[0]
        for other_version in versions:
            if apt_pkg.VersionCompare(version.VerStr, other_version.VerStr)<0:
                version = other_version

        if package.CurrentVer:
            current = package.CurrentVer
            if apt_pkg.VersionCompare(current.VerStr, version.VerStr)<0:
                return "upgradable"
            else:
                return "current"
        else:
            return "uninstalled"
```

I want to find a good way of using apt_pkg/apt to get the details for each package that's a possible upgrade/update candidate?

The way I'm currently doing this, I only get updates/upgrades for packages already in the system, even though **I noticed the update manager for Debian shows me packages that I don't have in my system.**

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092983/29489 and checkout python-apt doc http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html

Comment: I've been studying the documentation, and i did look at that link a while ago, I commented on it (  
AttributeError: 'Package' object has no attribute 'isUpgradeable'... – Dayan Jan 3 at 20:55 ), but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script is based on your python code, works on my Ubuntu 12.04, should also works with any system has python-apt 0.8+

```
import apt

apt_cache = apt.Cache() #High level

apt_cache.update()
apt_cache.open()

list_pkgs = []

for package_name in apt_cache.keys():
    selected_package = apt_cache[package_name]

    #Verify that the package can be upgraded
    if selected_package.isUpgradable:
        pkg = dict(
            name=selected_package.name,
            version= selected_package.installedVersion,
            desc= selected_package.description,
            homepage= selected_package.homepage,
            severity= selected_package.priority)
        list_pkgs.append(pkg)

print list_pkgs
```

Comment: This is what throws me for a spin, i get a list of 195 updates available, but when I run updater it shows me 201??

Comment: @Dayan it could be some upgraded version of pkgs has new dependencies, thus bring in more pkgs to install. try to compare those two list to see what's in the missing six